# How to determine if date is current month/year then proceed with macro

Tags: excel, vba, date, macros

I have current date in B5, and a user entered effective date in B6.  I have a button activated macro that creates a .prn file

If effective date is not within current year or current month, then a message box should appear "Effective date is in the past.  Proceed?"  Then I need a Yes or No prompt.  If user selects Yes, then proceed with macro, if No, then exit.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There's no need to SHOUT your question. We can all read very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to compare your dates, then take appropriate action:

```
Sub compareDates()
  With ActiveSheet
    If Format(.Range("B5"), "myyyy") <> Format(.Range("B6"), "myyyy") Then
      If MsgBox("Effective date is in the past. Proceed?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    End If
  End With

  ' call your macro here

End Sub
```

Comment: DaveU - What would be the code for Yes or No?  I want it to proceed with the rest of the macro if pressed yes, and exit sub if pressed no.

Comment: DaveU  - thanks for taking the time, I'm really new at coding and still learning a lot

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Could you check this as answered?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry that took a while, I didn't know how to mark a question answered.